# Relative paths in ArcScene document are broken if opened programmatically

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-9.3, vba, arcscene

When I open ArcScene document with relative paths programmatically from ArcMap, all those paths are broken. The location in source tab for broken layers is set to some different path like "C:\Windows\System32" or "C:\Windows".

Below is the code sample I use to open document. Both ArcMap and ArcScene projects are located in "C:\test" and so are files added to ArcScene doc.

```
Sub test_relpaths()
  Dim pDoc As IDocument
  Set pDoc = New sxDocument
  Dim iApp As IApplication
  Set iApp = pDoc.Parent
  iApp.OpenDocument ("C:\test\test_relpaths.sxd")
End Sub
```

When I use similar code to open ArcMap doc from ArcScene, everything is fine, relative links are kept:

```
Sub test_relpaths()
  Dim pDoc As IDocument
  Set pDoc = New mxDocument
  Dim iApp As IApplication
  Set iApp = pDoc.Parent
  iApp.OpenDocument ("C:\test\test_relpaths.mxd")
End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue or tell if it's a bug.

**Update:** I've installed 9.3.1 with SP2 and some patches, but it didn't help.
**Update2:** I've also tested these samples in ArcGIS Desktop 10 SP3 and results are the same. It seems like an ArcScene bug.

Comment: Hi @Vlad and welcome to the site.  Can you please confirm that when you open the SXD normally that the relative paths are in fact not "broken". (this should be the same document you are attempting to open programmatically on the same machine)

Comment: Hi, @Jakub! Sorry for having missed it in my question. If I open SXD doc manually, all paths are correct. And they are correct when I reopen SXD after attempt to open it from ArcMap.